# How can I access an object's private members?

Tags: c++, oop, private, public

Let's say I have a class with an object for a member:

```
class Class1
{
    private:
        Class2 anObject;
}
```

And an integer variable and an accessor in the other class:

```
class Class2
{
    private:
        int aVariable;
    public:
        int getAVariable()
        {
             return aVariable;
        }
}
```

What's the best way to access `aVariable` from main?

For example, if `anObject` is declared public rather than private I can do this in main:

```
int main()
{
    Class1 Class1Object;
    cout << Class1Object.anObject.getAVariable() << '\n';
}
```

But how would I do this if `anObject` is kept private?

Comment: Seems like there could be a better design, but `main` is allowed to be a friend.

Comment: I think you should read a bit more about OOP principles..

Comment: @chris That sounds much worse than just adding a getter.

Comment: if you just want to print it out, just overload `operator<<` for `Class1`

Comment: @polkadotcadaver, Hence why I said better design.

Comment: First, do you understand the whole point of `private`?

Comment: Why not read a dictionary and the meaning of PRIVATE?

Comment: @JimBalter: To protect the data through encapsulation.

Comment: Then why do you want to violate encapsulation? Anyway, it isn't to "protect the data", it's to encapsulate the implementation ... outsiders should not depend on that variable existing or having particular semantics.

Comment: @JimBalter: I don't that's why I was asking this question.

Comment: That response made no sense. Your question has nothing to do with why you want to violate encapsulation, it's asking how to do so.

Comment: @JimBalter: Well I asked how I keep anObject private but still be able to read the object data through a method. I don't want to violate encapsulation if it can be avoided.

Comment: Proper methods don't expose object data, they yield properties or values, which may or may not be implemented in terms of specific objects. To just create an accessor whose name replicates the name of a variable violates encapsulation because the name doesn't reflect a semantic property and it becomes a misnomer if the object is later eliminated from the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get a public getter for the object you want in class 1.

```
public:
    Class2 getObject()
    {
         return anObject;
    }
```

and then you can do

```
 int main()

{
Class1 Class1Object;
cout << Class1Object.getObject().getAVariable() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: encapsulation is about having the fields be private, and make them only readable through getters, and modifiable through setters..

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. Thanks for the suggestion aafonso1991.

Comment: My other thought was to simply extend Class2 from Class1. Then an object created from Class1 (Class1Object) would have access to the getAVariable() function.

Comment: You only want to extend Class2 from Class1 if they have similar behavior and fields. Say Class1 is an "animal" and class2 is a "dog", then you should use inheritance since a dog is an animal and it also has the properties that an animal has...but if the Class1 and Class2 don't share anything in common(i.e class1 is a "shark" and class2 is a "dog" then they shouldn't inherit from each other, because a shark has methods that are way different from a dog...but they both can extend the animal class because they're both animals...")

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you could define an accessor (get function) on Class1 that simply returns the result of calling getAVariable() on Class2.

Comment: I was thinking of this, but it seemed strange. Would it not be better to simply declare anObject public?

Comment: @navig8tr What was the reason for declaring it private in the first place?

Comment: @navig8tr - Being private it can be a) read only. b) be calculated or just a value (depending on implementation of the class)

Comment: @JimBalter: To demonstrate encapsulation. This is for school.

Comment: @navig8tr You said you made it private to achieve encapsulation - if it's public, then it's not encapsulated any more.

Comment: @navig8tr Ah, so school wants you to understand the concept, and you're busy not understanding it. Encapsulation was demonstrated by your not being able to access the variable from main; asking how to do so doesn't make sense.

Comment: GetAVariable() is the worst possible name for a function, and reflects complete failure to understand basic concepts. GetFoo(), where Foo is some property, is a proper function name, and GetFoo() may or may not be a simple accessor of a value ... that's up to the implementation.

Comment: @JimBalter: In this case I would still like to be able to read the data. And yes making it public would defeat the purpose of encapsulation. I'm just looking for the best way to do this.

Comment: @JimBalter: This is just a quick dummy situation. I didn't give much thought to the names of variables.

Comment: @navig8tr By not giving consideration to names of variables you are failing to encapsulate. Creating accessor functions with names that imply a backing variable violates encapsulation. Just slapping `private` on things and making accessors to them does not encapsulate, it's a phony cargo cult shadow of encapsulation.

Comment: @JimBalter: Thanks for tip. You've been so helpful.

Comment: I guess the way to go in this situation would be to follow AboutAverage's advice. That is, unless I can find a better way to design the system

Comment: @navig8tr My suggestion is to provide an accessor function that has a name describing a property, like GetAverageHeight() or some such, and name your variable something like CalculatedAverageHeight, with a comment in the function saying that it could calculate the average height on the fly instead of keeping it in a variable. That would show that you understand the concepts involved.

Comment: What if I simply extended Class2 from Class1. Then an object created from Class1 (Class1Object) would have access to the getAVariable() function?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

```
class Class1
{
    public:
        int getAVariable()                   //Option 1, Get the int directly
        {
            return anObject.getAVariable()
        }
        Class2 getAnObject()                 //Option 2, Get a copy of the object
        {                                    
            return anObject
        } 
    private:
        Class2 anObject;
}
```

Option 1: is what AboutAverage suggested.  But then if you had more than one private members in `Class2` then you would need an accessor for each in `Class1`

Option 2: Is what aafonso1991 just beat me to. It returns a copy of the `anObject` so `anObject` in `Class1` still isn't modified.  It's the better OO choice because you won't need to create extra functions and save those lines of code.  It could be an issue at run time though if Class2 is particularly large and copying it is expensive.  In that case, you could create accessors of like option1 to commonly desired members of `Class1`